# How do I upgrade my Heroku SendGrid integration now that they require two-factor authentication?

Tags: heroku, sendgrid

I'm very confused by the new SendGrid changes. What do I need to change?

I received an email:

```
We are emailing to inform you that Twilio SendGrid now requires you to authenticate with API Keys, and we require Two-Factor Authentication (2FA) to login to your account as of February 17th, 2021.This requirement is in order to ensure uninterrupted service and improve the security of your account. Our records show that one or more users on your account used basic authentication with username and password for one or more of your SendGrid API requests or SMTP configuration within the last 4 months. If you did not take action, your API and SMTP requests will be rejected starting February 17th, 2021.
```

I don't think my setup is using the API keys, though I have one in my env vars:

```rb
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

My SendGrid account shows a marked reduction in mails sent around the 17th, as stated in the email, but there is still some activity, which is confusing:

[image]

I'm using `sendgrid-ruby (5.3.0)` ruby gem

The [new documentation on SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/rubyonrails/) seems to say send api keys as username and password:

```rb
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => 'apikey',
  :password => 'your_sendgrid_api_key',
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

But what is `apikey` and how is it different from `your_sendgrid_api_key`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you are sending emails with SendGrid using SMTP you need to authenticate yourself. SMTP uses basic authentication which requires a username and a password. In order to use an API key as the password, we also need a username.

Since the API key is all you need to actually authenticate yourself the username is a sort of placeholder. So, in the example the username is "apikey" but that is literally what it should be set to: "apikey".

The password should then be set to your API key, which you [create in the SendGrid admin console](https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/api-keys/#creating-an-api-key). So the code should be something like:

```rb
username = "apikey"
password = ENV["SENDGRID_API_KEY"]

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :user_name => username,
  :password => password,
  :domain => 'yourdomain.com',
  :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
  :port => 587,
  :authentication => :plain,
  :enable_starttls_auto => true
}
```

Comment: This is much clearer with the variables! I would suggest you replace the code in the docs with this. Thank you.